# Create the TextBoxfor With Two entity model columns in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

1st I explain my scenario, I have created the Columns in DB Like CountryCode,PhoneNumber
and create the Model and Controller

In View we need to show the CountryCode along with PhoneNumber like this(+91 9856254874) in textbox

when user changed the textbox value and submit i need to update respective two columns by splitting the code and phone number

How can i Achieve this?

This is my Model:

```
 public partial class Details
 {
    public Nullable<int> ContryCode { get; set; }
    public string        PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
 }
```

This is my expectation on View But its not working

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContryCode+" "+ model => model.PhoneNumber, new { placeholder = "Mobile Number", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "mobilenumber",@id="MobileNumber"})
```

This Textbox located inside the @Html.BeginForm when i click the submit button i need to update the DB with Separated ContryCode and PhoneNumber from the textbox

Kindly Help me on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You cant bind a control to 2 properties. Either create 2 text boxes, or create a view model with a property to represent the whole phone number, then post that back and split it in the controller (or create a custom model binder)

Comment: You would normally use two inputs, one for the country code and one for the phone numbers.

Comment: Even we cannot do anything with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that I can see is to just create two different textboxes for the two fields.

However, you can also create a ViewModel with a string property that concatenates the ContryCode and PhoneNumber, something like this:

```
public partial class DetailsViewModel
{
    public Nullable<int> ContryCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumberWithContryCode 
    {
         get
         {
             return string.Format("+{0} {1}", ContryCode, PhoneNumber);
         }
         set
         {
              // Code to parse the string to ContryCode and PhoneNumber
         }
}
```

However, you would have a lot more to think about for this option, specifically validation. What if there's no +? What if there's no space? Etc.

If JavaScript is fair game, you can use your original View, but bind your ContryCode and PhoneNumber properties to hidden fields. And then include a textbox in the form where you concatenate the values of ContryCode and PhoneNumber. When this textbox changes value, have some JavaScript code update the values of the hidden fields. This is essentially still similar to the suggestion above, with the parsing/validating moved to pure JavaScript.

I still advice that you keep it simple and use two textboxes instead.

Comment: I have solved this problem by writing the viewModel only like there in this Answer    public                                             string PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", ContryCode,Mobile);
            }
            set
            {
                Mobile = value.Replace("+"+MobileContryCode.ToString().Replace(" ", ""),"");
            }
        }