# How to Combine 2 textbox data in 1 textbox in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 project, I have First Name and Last Name as 2 separate textboxes. I need to combine these 2 and shows as one textbox as Customer Name how I can do that?

This is what I have now that shows 2 text boxes:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First_Name, new{disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Last_Name, new{disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create the TextBoxfor With Two entity model columns in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796091/create-the-textboxfor-with-two-entity-model-columns-in-mvc)

Comment: Why? You can easily create one textbox and bind it to another property (say `string FullName`) but when you post back you would need to parse the string to get the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties. And what if the value if "John Reese Jones" - is the first name "John Reece" or is the last name "Reece Jones"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fields are truly *combined* then you'd add a property to your model representing the new single field:

```
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

and use it in your view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerName, new{disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
```

(Though if, when saving back to the server, you need to parse the values back out into two separate fields then that can get tricky.  Don't make too many [assumptions about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  But if you must, then that parsing should likely happen in the setter for this property and the getter should dynamically display the concatenated values as below.)

If, on the other hand, it should be a read-only display of the combined values, you'd create a read-only property to view the other values:

```
public string CustomerName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", First_Name, Last_Name); }
}
```

and you can simply display it in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerName)
```

or just bind directly to the value in your own markup:

```
<span>@Model.CustomerName</span>
```

(In this approach you might also write some JavaScript to update the client-side displayed value as the values in the other fields change.)

It really depends on what you want to do with this field, if it saves back to the model or is only for display purposes.